# How to Split a PXSmartPanel window using PXSplitContainer

Tags: asp.net, acumatica

Is it possible to split a PXSmartPanel window into 2 Grid? This what I have tried so far but it's not working.

```
<px:PXSplitContainer>
<template1>
    <px:PXSmartPanel>
    <px:PXFormview>
    ...
    ...
    </px:PXFormview>
    <px:PXGrid>
    ...
    ...
    </px:PXGrid>

</template1>
<template2>
    <px:PXGrid>
    ...
    ...
    </px:PXGrid>
</template2>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
</px:PXSplitContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PXSmartPanel is a UI container control that renders a dialog box.
Think of it like a Dialog Window in an operating system.
It's a top level container so you can't split a PXSmartPanel into 2 grids.

Perhaps what you want is to have 2 grids separated by a split container inside a PXSmartPanel like the mockup below:
[image: Smart Panel Split Container]
You can achieve this layout with the following elements:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel>
    <px:PXSplitContainer>
        <Template1>
            <px:PXGrid/>
        </Template1>

        <Template2>
            <px:PXGrid/>
        </Template2>
    </px:PXSplitContainer>

    <px:PXPanel>
        <px:PXButton/>
        <px:PXButton/>
    </px:PXPanel>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```